# Overriding hook_menu() { $items }

Tags: 7, routes

For example, here's a snippet form the Comments Module (comment.module):

```
function comment_menu() {
  $items['comment/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Comment permalink',
    'page callback' => 'comment_permalink',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access comments'),
  );
  $items['comment/reply/%node'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add new comment',
    'page callback' => 'comment_reply',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access callback' => 'node_access',
    'access arguments' => array('view', 2),
    'file' => 'comment.pages.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

How can I override `$items['comment/%']` with `$items['comment/reply/%node']`, without hacking core.

In other words, I need `example.com/comment/[cid]` to look exactly like `example.com/comment/reply/[nid]/[cid]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you should use [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/hook_menu_alter)
Create new module and add hook_menu_alter

```
function my_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
    // Unset core path
    unset($items['comment/%']);
    $items['your/pass/here/%node'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add new comment',
        ...
      );
}
```

But link "comment/reply/%nid/%cid" is used by Drupal for replies to other comments (where %nid - node id and %cid - comment id you are replying to). Use another path.

Comment: How safe is it to unset the $item? I'm asking, because in some instances you're preferred to use hide(), etc...

Comment: well. really all information about menu callbacks are stored in DB - table "menu_router".

This table is updated when you are flushing cache. While flushing - drupal reads all hook_menu and hook_menu_alter functions. So after unset - just you will get row with such callback in this table.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and pass the same page callback and arguments.

Comment: Is there a function that can do that in template.php?

Comment: menu alter should be implemented in a module. I personally am not aware of a way to override the menu at the template level.